# pyarrow compute expression in reticulate

Tags: r, reticulate

How do I use a filter in a reticulate pyarrow compute expression.

At base I have a pyarrow dataset (in this case called `woodcan`) that I want to turn into a table with a filter.

```
tab <- woodcan$to_table(ds$field('Region')=='Canada')
```

The above gets `Error in py_compare_impl(a, b, op) :  ValueError: An Expression cannot be evaluated to python True or False. If you are using the 'and', 'or' or 'not' operators, use '&', '|' or '~' instead.`

How is that syntax supposed to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the expression running python code with `py_run_string` or `py_run_file` and pass it to `filter` argument of `to_table`:

```
library(reticulate)

run.py <- py_run_string('
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
expr = ds.field("Region") == "Canada"
')

woodcan$to_table(filter=run.py$expr)
```

Above code needs previous installation of `py_arrow` in conjuction with `reticulate`:

```
virtualenv_create("arrow-env")
arrow::install_pyarrow("arrow-env")
use_virtualenv("arrow-env")
```

Answer (score 1):

With @Waldi's answer I came up with another way that doesn't rely on python strings.

From that answer we generate `run.py$expr` which is a `<pyarrow.compute.Expression (Region == "Canada")>` object.

From there it begs the question, how else can we generate that?  Since it's a `pyarrow.compute.Expression` that tells us we need, of course, pyarrow.compute

so then it's just replacing "==" with `equal`

```
pc <- import('pyarrow.compute')
filter=pc$equal(pc$field("Region"), pc$scalar("Canada"))
```

and finally

```
woodcan$to_table(filter=filter)
```